# Why do DLLs have a private section?

Tags: c++, dll

Based on what I've read about exporting symbols from a DLL in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=msvc-170), you can tell the linker to not include a symbol in the .lib import file by appending the `PRIVATE` keyword to the export. This, in effect, hides that symbol from application code that uses the library.

My question is, doesn't the C++ keyword `static` already make variables/functions invisible to any external translation units?

Comment: But what if you have multiple translation units in your dll that need to share a symbol but you don't want that symbol used outside the dll?

Comment: Or what if you are building the DLL in a language other than C++? DLLs are language agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` and `PRIVATE` (wrt. DLLs, similar to [`-fvisibility=hidden`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) for Linux DSOs) are two different concepts.

The C++ standard as such is agnostic to DLLs and its implementations on different operating systems. `static` is applied on a translation unit (TU) level, i.e. it restricts the visibility of a symbol (function/variable) to the file it was defined in. So if you have two files `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, neither can see the static symbols of the other. Say you define a function `static void foo()` in `a.cpp`. There is no way `b.cpp` (or any other TU) can see `foo()`, because you've restricted its visibility to the file it was defined in.

On the contrary, `PRIVATE` restricts visibility on the DLL level, i.e. what is accessible when using the DLL. Meaning that the function `void bar()` (note: *non*-static) defined in `a.cpp` can be used by `b.cpp`, either by an `extern` declaration or by including some header `a.h`. However if you declare `bar()` as PRIVATE in your `.DEF` file, users of your DLL won't be able to call `bar()`, because the respective symbol won't be exported.

In that respect, `static` is a bit more restrictive than `PRIVATE`, because it already restricts visibility on TU level.

Comment: PRIVATE exports the symbol but excludes it from the lib. It is usually used for functions which are intended to be obtained via GetProcAddress, such as DllCanUnloadNow. You don't want this in B's lib because that would cause dll A's DllCanUnloadNow to be a forwarder to B's DllCanUnloadNow (which reports on B's objects), rather than reporting on A's objects.